# Expected } in C code

Tags: c

So, keep having problems with this calculator I'm making (Still learning C), it's giving me an error at the very end of the code, 'Expected }'. But I have } at the end, Ive added another one to see if that would work, but then it says 'Expected while in do/while loop'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    float number[100];
    int operator = '0';
    int doAgainAnswer = 0;
    int doAgain;
    float finished;
    int error;
    do{
        if(number[1] == 0){
            printf("Number 1: ");
            scanf("%f", &number[1]);
        } else if(number[1] != 0) {
            printf("\n\nNumber 1: %.2f\n", number[1]);


            printf("Number 2: ");
            scanf("%f", &number[2]);
            printf("\nOperator:\n1 Addition\n2 Subract\n3 Multiply\n4 Divide.\nChoice: ");
            scanf("%d", &operator);

            if(operator == 1){
                finished = number[1] + number[2];
                printf("\n\n%.2f \+ %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);

            }
            if(operator == 2){
                finished = number[1] - number[2];
                printf("\n\n%.2f \- %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);

            }
            if(operator == 3){
                finished = number[1] * number[2];
                printf("\n\n%.2f \* %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);

            }
            if(operator == 4){
                finished = number[1] / number[2];
                printf("\n\n%.2f \/ %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);
            }

            if(operator > 4){
                printf("\n\nERROR: Invalid operation.\n\n ");
                error = '1';
            }
            if(error != 1){
                printf("\nContinue?\n1: Yes\n2: Yes and use answer as starting value.\n3: No\nAnswer: ");
            } else if(error == 1){
                printf("\nTry again? 1 Yes 3 No: ");
            }
            scanf("%d", &doAgainAnswer);
            if(doAgainAnswer == 1) {
                doAgain = 1;
            } else

                if(doAgainAnswer == 2){
                    doAgain = 1;
                    number[1] = finished;

                } else
                    if(doAgainAnswer == 3){
                        doAgain = 0;
                        printf("Goodbye :(");
                        exit(0);
                    } else
                        if(doAgainAnswer > 4){
                            printf("\n\nERROR INVALID OPERATION.\n\n");
                        }
        }while(doAgain == 1);
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Your indentation suggests there should be a `}` after the first `else if` in the `do-while` loop

Comment: Find an editor that will auto-indent for you - it makes it much easier to spot mismatched braces. Also, many good editors will have a feature to highlight or jump between matching braces.

Comment: A correct indendation would make the problem obvious.

Comment: Here you go, I indented it for you.

Comment: You're missing several `{` and `}` in your code. Try formatting your code differently (to align each opening `{` and it's matching `}`, and see what you get. I found three missing ones in just a few seconds using Notepad++ and nothing more than the Enter, Space, and DownArrow keys.

Comment: @Useless, I'm not sure your indentation is correct... But for the record, it's not easy to guess where is the missing `}` :).

Comment: That's auto-indented, so it isn't _mine_ ... but you can see the `}while` lines up with the `} else if (number[1]` instead of the `do{`, and narrow it down from there.

Comment: `number[100];` is uninitialized. period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this part of your code contains an `else` which is never closed, i.e.:

```
 if(number[1] == 0)
 {
    printf("Number 1: ");
    scanf("%f", &number[1]);
 } 
 else if(number[1] != 0) 
 {
   ....
 } <-- missing.
```

Whole code block, reformatted slightly differently:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    float number[100];
    int operator = '0';
    int doAgainAnswer = 0;
    int doAgain;
    float finished;
    int error;
    do
    {
        if(number[1] == 0)
        {
            printf("Number 1: ");
            scanf("%f", &number[1]);
        } 
        else if(number[1] != 0) 
        {
            printf("\n\nNumber 1: %.2f\n", number[1]);            
            printf("Number 2: ");
            scanf("%f", &number[2]);
            printf("\nOperator:\n1 Addition\n2 Subract\n3 Multiply\n4 Divide.\nChoice: ");
            scanf("%d", &operator);

            if(operator == 1)
            {
                finished = number[1] + number[2];
                printf("\n\n%.2f \+ %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);
            }

            if(operator == 2)
            {
                finished = number[1] - number[2];
                printf("\n\n%.2f \- %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);                
            }

            if(operator == 3)
            {
                finished = number[1] * number[2];
                printf("\n\n%.2f \* %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);                
            }

            if(operator == 4)
            {
                finished = number[1] / number[2];
                printf("\n\n%.2f \/ %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);
            }

            if(operator > 4)
            {
                printf("\n\nERROR: Invalid operation.\n\n ");
                error = '1';
            }

            if(error != 1)
            {
                printf("\nContinue?\n1: Yes\n2: Yes and use answer as starting value.\n3: No\nAnswer: ");
            } 
            else if(error == 1)
            {
                printf("\nTry again? 1 Yes 3 No: ");
            }

            scanf("%d", &doAgainAnswer);
            if(doAgainAnswer == 1) 
            {
                doAgain = 1;
            } 
            else if(doAgainAnswer == 2)
            {
                doAgain = 1;
                number[1] = finished;
            } 
            else if(doAgainAnswer == 3)
            {
                doAgain = 0;
                printf("Goodbye :(");
                exit(0);
            } 
            else if(doAgainAnswer > 4)
            {
                printf("\n\nERROR INVALID OPERATION.\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
    while(doAgain == 1);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Proper indentation and using matching brackets even in conditionals that contain a single call always make things clearer!

Comment: @emartel Totally agree! Also important is consistent placement of spaces.  Too many people write `if(...){`, `if (...){`, `if (...) {`, ... etc. all in one file/project.

Answer (score 2):

```
else if(number[1] != 0) {
printf("\n\nNumber 1: %.2f\n", number[1]);
```

You never close this else if statement.

Comment: Aha I edited that line of code, how didn't I guess that. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

To prevent errors like this from happening, I suggest that you use a different kind of indentation.

If you write your code like this:

```
int main()
{
    float number[100];
    int operator = '0';
    int doAgainAnswer = 0;
    int doAgain;
    float finished;
    int error;
    do
    {
        if(number[1] == 0)
        {
           printf("Number 1: ");
           scanf("%f", &number[1]);
        }
        else if(number[1] != 0)
        {
            printf("\n\nNumber 1: %.2f\n", number[1]);

        printf("Number 2: ");
        scanf("%f", &number[2]);
        printf("\nOperator:\n1 Addition\n2 Subract\n3 Multiply\n4 Divide.\nChoice: ");
        scanf("%d", &operator);
```

You should notice instantly that there's a `}`missing after the `else if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try having writing the {} in newlines and having them with no code  in that line. it will help you get organized and find problems easier!

Answer (score 1):

Proper indentation shows that you are missing a `}` to match your first `else if {`.

You really need to use a proper editor (one that at least does auto-indentation), use `{}` around your `else`s to avoid dangling them*, and use helper functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{
    ...
    do{
        if(number[1] == 0){
            printf("Number 1: ");
            scanf("%f", &number[1]);
        } else if(number[1] != 0) {
            ...
        }while(doAgain == 1);
        return 0;

    }
```

*: seriously, *always* use braces unless it's short enough to go on a single line (`else return`, or similar). I found this in code at my last company:

```
if(DEBUG) 
//    print(foo);

if(something_important) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs better indentation. With proper indentation it'd be easier to spot where the is (or is not) the missing bracket. You didn't close the outer `if/else` statement, right before the `while` condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    float number[100];
    int operator = '0';
    int doAgainAnswer = 0;
    int doAgain;
    float finished;
    int error;

    do {
        if(number[1] == 0) {
            printf("Number 1: ");
            scanf("%f", &number[1]);
        }
        else if (number[1] != 0) {
            printf("\n\nNumber 1: %.2f\n", number[1]);
            printf("Number 2: ");
            scanf("%f", &number[2]);
            printf("\nOperator:\n1 Addition\n2 Subract\n3 Multiply\n4 Divide.\nChoice: ");
            scanf("%d", &operator);

            if (operator == 1) {
                finished = number[1] + number[2];
                printf("\n\n%.2f \+ %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);
            }

            if (operator == 2) {
                finished = number[1] - number[2];
                printf("\n\n%.2f \- %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);
            }

            if (operator == 3) {
            finished = number[1] * number[2];
            printf("\n\n%.2f \* %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);
            }

            if (operator == 4) {
                finished = number[1] / number[2];
                printf("\n\n%.2f \/ %.2f is: %.2f", number[1], number[2], finished);
            }

            if (operator > 4) {
                printf("\n\nERROR: Invalid operation.\n\n ");
                error = '1';
            }

            if (error != 1) {
                printf("\nContinue?\n1: Yes\n2: Yes and use answer as starting value.\n3: No\nAnswer: ");
            }
            else if (error == 1) {
                printf("\nTry again? 1 Yes 3 No: ");
            }

            scanf("%d", &doAgainAnswer);

            if (doAgainAnswer == 1) {
                doAgain = 1;
            }
            else if(doAgainAnswer == 2) {
                doAgain = 1;
                number[1] = finished;
            }
            else if (doAgainAnswer == 3) {
                doAgain = 0;
                printf("Goodbye :(");
                exit(0);
            }
            else if (doAgainAnswer > 4) {
                printf("\n\nERROR INVALID OPERATION.\n\n");
            }
    /**
     * Missing a bracket here, to close the if/else statement
     */
        }
        while (doAgain == 1);

        return 0;
    }
// Indentation should end at this level
```